# When do we use « faillir » in a tense other than the perfect?

Tags: temps-grammatical

With the verb « faillir », I have never seen it used in a tense other than the perfect. Even for sentences in the present tense in english like "I always nearly miss the bus but never do", DeepL translates as "J'ai toujours failli manquer le bus mais je ne le fais jamais". When I plug other conjugations into context searchers like Reverso, for example « faillais », it only returns with one example of the anachronistic meaning of having failed a task instead of the modern usage of almost doing something. So I was wondering if anyone could provide some examples of « faillir » with its more popular meaning used in a tense that is not the perfect?

Comment: On peut aussi dire: rater le bus. What is the perfect tense for you? Passé composé?

Comment: *Je suis toujours à deux doigts de louper le bus, mais ça n'arrive jamais*

Comment: @jlliagre I thought you said:  "no need to correct something already right"

Comment: @Lambie That's what I wrote indeed. *Louper* is a colloquial synonym of *manquer*, both are correct.

Comment: louper, manquer, rater are all correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"J'ai toujours failli manquer le bus mais je ne le fais jamais" is not correct as a translation of "I always nearly miss the bus but never do". You have to use something else, such as, for instance,  "J'ai toujours failli manquer le bus mais ce n'est jamais arrivé.". Moreover, this is idiomatic only as a corrective in which "failli" is emphasized. A proper way to put that in French would be "Je suis toujours arrivé  à l'arrêt juste à temps pour prendre le bus et je ne l'ai jamais manqué.".

"Faillir' is one of the so called "verbes défectifs", this being meant to say that the forms for certain tenses do not exist. However, the reason for not finding it used in certain tenses is  really due to the rare use that is made of "faillir" in those tenses. In the spoken language other verbs are used; they are more specific.

> [Conjugaison Française](https://www.conjugaisonfrancaise.com/faillir.html) « Faillir » est employé surtout à l'infinitif, au passé simple et aux temps composés. Les autres formes conjuguées sont rares. Faillir (+ infinitif), toujours à un temps du passé = être sur le point de. J'ai failli tomber.

*Example*

- Si je faillis, eux sont là, juste derrière, pour me relever et me remettre sur le droit chemin. Ils me scotchent les pieds au sol. Ils me portent. Ils m'encouragent. Ils m'aiment. Indéfectiblement. Sans condition. (*literary use, [Et si c'était à refaire](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22si%20je%20faillis%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)*)
- Si je n'y arrive pas/Si je me trompe/Si je ne suis pas dans la bonne voie/Si je fais une erreur/…

There are no popular uses of "faillir" of the sort you are seeking.

Comment: L'emploi du subjonctif present est aussi assez courant : *il ne faut pas que je faillisse*

Comment: @ArwynFr On trouve cet usage dans les livres de grammaire, beaucoup, mais dans l'expression moderne c'est assez rare. Voir par example les pages suivantes : https://www.google.com/search?q=%22que%20je%20faillisse%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr . Il n'y a que très peu de cas au 21e siècle. Cependant, je trouve que c'est toujours correct de l'utiliser.

Answer (score 1):

Le conditionnel est aussi usité : "Je faillirais à mon devoir si je ne l'aide pas", ainsi que le futur : "En révélant demain ce secret, je faillirai certes à mon obligation de discrétion, mais je le ferai néanmoins".

---

Oui en effet, "aidais".

Quoique, à y réfléchir, sur le plan sémantique, "si je ne l'aide pas" pose une condition, alors pourquoi dans ce cas, ne pourrait on pas employer le conditionnel, justement ? La règle grammaticale est dans ce cas discutable...;) Remplaçons par : "supposons que je ne l'aide pas : je faillirais a mon devoir".

Comment: Je dirais plutôt : « Je faillirais à mon devoir si je ne l'aid**ais** pas »